# javascript function stops browser's tab

Tags: javascript, function, progress-bar, processing

I have a problem with processing a Javascript `function`
in the code below a simple example
when I click the button in that code a Javascript `function` starts to process
that function must change the value of the progress bar while it's processing and the text area is shows when you try to type in that the page stopped and after a few seconds the browser gives a message

**I intend to ensure that the function shows the value of the progress bar and I would like to do some tasks while the function is loading**

```js
       function f() {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += i;
                document.getElementById("r").value += 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <progress max="100000" value="0" id="r"></progress>
    <button onclick="f()">click here</button>
    <textarea placeholder="type here ..."></textarea>
    <p id="p"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Small note: The function is appending "i" to the P element rather than changing the number inside to "i", which makes this run much slower. Use `document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = i;` instead.

Comment: @Lemondoge true, but the main problem is that Javascript is single-threaded and has no means to run this using a different thread (except WebWorkers, but since the UI needs to be updated in all steps, this does not seem to be a WebWorkers problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Javascript is single-threaded. The browser is fully focusing on the calculations and does not have time to redraw. To remedy this, we need to provide some time to the browser to regroup:

```js
       function f() {
            var i = 0;
            var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += i;
                document.getElementById("r").value += 1;
                if (++i === 100000) clearInterval(intervalID);
            }, 50);
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <progress max="100000" value="0" id="r"></progress>
    <button onclick="f()">click here</button>
    <textarea placeholder="type here ..."></textarea>
    <p id="p"></p>

</body>

</html>
```